# Le contraire de « sans parler »

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, néerlandais

J'ai besoin d’une traduction du mot « hardop ». C’est le contraire de « sans parler », ou « en réfléchissant ».

Auparavant, j’utilisais un mauvais dictionnaire qui me donnait « tapageur ». Plus tard, j'ai recherché ce mot dans le Wiktionnaire pour la certitude, et c’est alors que j’ai découvert que ce mot n’était pas convenable. J’introduisais donc « hardop » dans la boite, et ce site m’a rendu les traductions suivantes :

- fort
- à haute voix
- à voix haute

Je trouvais ça surprenant que « fort » appartient à cet ensemble. Les sens de ce mot me semblent trop nombreux pour l’utiliser sans ambiguïté ici. En plus, je ne sais pas comment insérer ce mot dans une phrase. Je suis donc enclin à le laisser de côté, sauf si vous pouvez me dire comment l’emploi de ce mot se déroule ici.

Il me semble que « à haute voix » ou « à voix haute » sous-entend qu’on crie, et je veux éviter ce sous-entendu. 
Je dirais que la tournure « en parlant » est un assez bon choix pour exprimer le sens voulu :
*Ces gens comptaient en parlant. Il lisait le dernier chapitre de son livre en parlant.*
Bien que cela laisse penser qu’on interrompt sa besogne parfois pour avoir un entretien avec quelqu’un.

Que conseillez-vous ?

Comment: Dans les exemples cités *en parlant* signifie que les gens font deux choses à la fois : ils comptent et parlent de tout autre chose que des calculs qu'ils sont en train de réaliser.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

« Compter **à voix haute** », ou « lire **à voix haute** », n'ont pas de rapport avec le volume de la parole ; cela signifie simplement que la personne qui compte, ou lit, le fait en parlant plutôt qu'en réfléchissant.

« **à voix haute** » (ou éventuellement « **à haute voix** ») semblent donc être de bonnes traductions dans le contexte que tu décris.

Quant à l'usage de « **fort** », dans ce cas il serait plutôt à opposer à « silencieusement », donc ne signifierait pas nécessairement que la personne crie : je dirais que ça reste une traduction possible, mais pas la plus élégante (tout comme « **en parlant** »). J'aurais plutôt tendance à choisir « à voix haute ».

Enfin, « **tapageur** » fait référence à quelqu'un qui fait beaucoup de bruit (ou de « tapage », par exemple du « tapage nocturne », lorsque les voisins font trop de bruit la nuit) de manière fréquente. J'y verrais même une notion péjorative. Ça ne me semble pas du tout adapté à la situation que tu décris.